# Long term effects of chewing on cheek?

Tags: dermatology, oral-health

When I'm concentrating hard or anxious I unconsciously start biting my cheeks, sometimes biting off the topmost layer of skin. I don't bleed, but the sensation of the skin is bumpy instead of smooth.

I have done some googling, but can't seem to get anything else than articles related to peeling of the skin inside the mouth (e.g. http://www.webdental.com/profiles/blogs/the-inside-of-my-mouth-is-peeling-what-s-going-on), which is definitely not similar to my situation.

Has anyone heard of this kind of fixation, and is there any potential health risks associated with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The greatest risk of this is sore formation, thickening of skin due to callus and infection. As infection,  callus and sores can be disfiguring and debilitating this is a formidable problem. However, most issues come from the deeper skin being broken.

[Morsicatio buccarum et labiorum](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1867357)

> In some individuals habitual cheek and lip biting becomes a fixed
>   neurosis. Pieces of oral mucosa are actually torn free from the
>   surface, producing a distinctive clinical appearance termed morsicatio
>   buccarum et labiorum.

This disorder though probably not what your looking for us what extreme cases can turn into.

[Oral Frictional Hyperkeratosis](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/1076089-clinical#b1)

> Most patients with frictional keratosis are free of symptoms, with the
>   exception of those with aggressive cheek and lip biting habits. In
>   some individuals who repeatedly traumatize the tissues, tenderness,
>   swelling, and a burning sensation may be presenting symptoms. Patients
>   with persistent cheek and lip biting habits tend to have increased
>   stress and psychologic disorders. A patient may notice a thickening or
>   roughness of the involved mucosal site, or frictional keratosis may be
>   discovered as an incidental finding during a routine oral examination.

The [risk of cancer](http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/165331.php) from this seems low, but consulting a doctor or dentist would be the best course of action.

[Goodtherapy.com](http://www.goodtherapy.org/blog/ever-wondered-why-you-bite-the-insides-of-your-cheeks-0630144)

[Sharecare.com](https://www.sharecare.com/health/healthy-teeth-and-mouth/chewing-inside-of-cheek)

Comment: Although there is practically no chance that Hyperkeratosis will turn into cancer, if this is bothering the patient reating/eliminating the underlying cause of stress would be recommended, by for instance going to see a psychologist.